# Error al usar BroadcastReceiver

Tags: java, android

Estoy haciendo uso de `BroadcastReceiver` tal cual lo indica la documentación oficial de android pero no me funciona

```java
public class MyBroadcastReceiver   extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private static final String TAG = "MyBroadcastReceiver";
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("Action: " + intent.getAction() + "\n");
        sb.append("URI: " + intent.toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME).toString() + "\n");
        String log = sb.toString();
        Log.d(TAG, log);
        Toast.makeText(context, log, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

```java
        BroadcastReceiver br = new MyBroadcastReceiver();

        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION);
        filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_AIRPLANE_MODE_CHANGED);
        this.registerReceiver(br, filter);
```

No recibo el evento, se me muestra este error en el log:

> E/ActivityManager: Sending non-protected broadcast
>   com.motorola.internal.intent.action.DATA_UNAVAILABLE_FOR_OOS from
>   system 2024:com.motorola.modemservice/1000 pkg
>   com.motorola.bach.modemstats
>       java.lang.Throwable
>           at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.checkBroadcastFromSystem(ActivityManagerService.java:19149)
>           at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.broadcastIntentLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:19771)
>           at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.broadcastIntent(ActivityManagerService.java:19904)
>           at android.app.ActivityManagerNative.onTransact(ActivityManagerNative.java:514)
>           at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:3054)
>           at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:570)

lo he echo con el `<receiver>` en el manifest y también lo he echo sin el , es el mismo error , lo he probado en dos dispositivos físicos y en el emulador , ocurre lo mismo en todos , 
lo que busco en ultima instancia es saber cuando mi app tenga o no internet , pero no me esta funcionando siquiera el ejemplo de la documentación , alguien pos favor sabe como hacer que esto funcione

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Desde la forma dinámica que estas definiendo, puedes utilizar lo siguiente.
Ya sea en el **onCreate()** u **onResume()**.

```
IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
intentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_AIRPLANE_MODE_CHANGED);
reciver = new airplanemodecheck();
registerReceiver(reciver, intentFilter);
```

Solo recuerda quitar el registro antes de que la actividad se destruya, en el **onStop()**.

```
unregisterReceiver(reciver);
```

Por ultimo en la clase que extienda a BroadcastReceiver, podrás obtener el resultado de los eventos, que registraste.

```
if(Settings.System.getInt(context.getContentResolver(), Settings.Global.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON, 0)== 0){
 //
}
else{
 //
}
```